# LuaJ add lua function in Java

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I am aware of this method:

[How can I add functions to _G that run java code using Luaj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431693/how-can-i-add-functions-to-g-that-run-java-code-using-luaj)

But that link lets you add functions such as `math.abs(...)`. I just want to add functions without libraries or having to use `require`, you can just use `myfunction()` right out of the box.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the LuaJ source:

```
public LuaValue call(LuaValue modname, LuaValue env)
{
    globals = env.checkglobals();

    env.set("assert", new _assert());
    env.set("collectgarbage", new collectgarbage());
    env.set("dofile", new dofile());
            ....

    return env;
}
```